# Random path for CCK fields inside form array

Tags: entities

I have created a custom entity and i'm using CCK fields. Each bundle has it's own fields. For example:

```
function MYMODULE_install() {
  // Check if our field is not already created.
  if (!field_info_field('field_myField')) {
    $field = array(
        'field_name' => 'date_field',
        'type' => 'list_text',
    );
    field_create_field($field);
}
```

//Enable is executed only once.

```
function bundle_callback_enable() {

  // Create the instance on the bundle.
  $instance = array(
    'field_name' => 'date_field',
    'entity_type' => 'payment_method',
    'label' => 'Expiration Date',
    'bundle' => 'card',
    'required' => TRUE,
    'settings' => array();

  field_create_instance($instance);
}
```

My bundles are created from individual modules, so in each install file i am creating the respective fields.

Yesterday i tried to add validation callback functions in those fields and i saw something weird inside form array. Fields with type="text" had the path:

```
$form[field_name]['und'][0][value] // expectable
```

but fields with type='list_text' had only the path:

```
$form[field_name]['und'] // unexpectable
```

I couldn't find any solution and i've solved it with this way:

```
function &get_cck_path_value( $field_name, &$form_path) {

  $field = null
  if ( isset( $form_path[$field_name][LANGUAGE_NONE] )) {
     $field = &$form_path[$field_name][LANGUAGE_NONE]
  }
  elseif(isset($form_path[$field_name][LANGUAGE_NONE][0])) {
    $field =  &$form_path[$field_name][LANGUAGE_NONE][0]['value'];
  }
  return $field;
}
```

I don't like this approach. Is too hucky. Can you tell me if that is a cck feature or bug? I can't understand when it decides where to put the values( All the process is fulfilled through the "field_attach_form( ... )" )?

Have you faced any problem like this?

Thanks.